# Handling nested zip files with archive/zip

Tags: go, zip

I'm struggling to handle nested zip files in Go (where a zip file contains another zip file). I'm trying to recurse a zip file and list all of the files it contains.

archive/zip gives you two methods for handling a zip file:

- zip.NewReader
- zip.OpenReader

`OpenReader` opens a file on disk. `NewReader` accepts an `io.ReaderAt` and a file size. As you iterate through the zipped files with either of these, you get out a `zip.File` for each file inside the zip. To get the file contents of file f, you call `f.Open` which gives you a `zip.ReadCloser`. To open a nested zip file, I'd need to use `NewReader`, but `zip.File` and `zip.ReadCloser` do not satisfy the `io.ReaderAt` interface.

`zip.File` has a private field `zipr` which is an `io.ReaderAt` and `zip.ReadCloser` has a private field `f` which is an `os.File` which should satisfy the requirements for `NewReader`.

My question: is there any way to open a nested zip file without first writing the contents to a file on disk, or reading the whole thing into memory.

It looks like everything that is needed is available in zip.File, but isn't exported. I'm hoping I missed something.

Comment: I fear the simplest thing to do would be to copy it into a `bytes.Buffer` or to disk. How big are the nested zips?

Comment: You may find the api for https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/vfs/zipfs a bit more accommodating as well. Not sure.

Comment: @captncraig This is for a small scanning program so I won't know what zip files I'll encounter. I'm not sure how common this will be either, I just felt so close to being able to plumb everything together using streams. Good call on the `bytes.Buffer`, I suppose I can just check file sizes before reading the whole thing since I have access to that.

Comment: Just be careful for things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642245/need-io-readerat-from-zip-archive-entry-the-entry-is-a-nested-xlsx-file

Answer (score 2):

How about an `io.ReaderAt` from an `io.Reader` that reinitializes if you decided to go backwards: (this code is largely untested, but hopefully you get the idea)

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type inefficientReaderAt struct {
    rdr    io.ReadCloser
    cur    int64
    initer func() (io.ReadCloser, error)
}

func newInefficentReaderAt(initer func() (io.ReadCloser, error)) *inefficientReaderAt {
    return &inefficientReaderAt{
        initer: initer,
    }
}

func (r *inefficientReaderAt) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = r.rdr.Read(p)
    r.cur += int64(n)
    return n, err
}

func (r *inefficientReaderAt) ReadAt(p []byte, off int64) (n int, err error) {
    // reset on rewind
    if off < r.cur || r.rdr == nil {
        r.cur = 0
        r.rdr, err = r.initer()
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
    }

    if off > r.cur {
        sz, err := io.CopyN(ioutil.Discard, r.rdr, off-r.cur)
        n = int(sz)
        if err != nil {
            return n, err
        }
    }

    return r.Read(p)
}

func main() {
    r := newInefficentReaderAt(func() (io.ReadCloser, error) {
        return ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("ABCDEFG")), nil
    })

    io.Copy(os.Stdout, io.NewSectionReader(r, 0, 3))
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, io.NewSectionReader(r, 1, 3))
}
```

If you mostly move forwards this probably works ok. Especially if you use a buffered reader.

- I should note that this violates the `io.ReaderAt` guarantees: https://godoc.org/io#ReaderFrom , namely it doesn't allow parallel calls to `ReadAt`, and doesn't block on full reads, so this may not even work properly

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same need and came up with the following approach, not sure if its any help to you:

```
// NewZipFromReader ...
func NewZipFromReader(file io.ReadCloser, size int64) (*zip.Reader, error) {
    in := file.(io.Reader)

    if _, ok := in.(io.ReaderAt); ok != true {
        buffer, err := ioutil.ReadAll(in)

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        in = bytes.NewReader(buffer)
        size = int64(len(buffer))
    }

    reader, err := zip.NewReader(in.(io.ReaderAt), size)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return reader, nil
}
```

So if `file` doesn't implement `io.ReaderAt` it reads the whole contents into a buffer.

It's probably not safe to handle ZIP bombs, and will defenitely fail with OOM for files larger than RAM.